# Incorporate date and time of execution of tests in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit

Is it possible to display the date and time that PHPUnit executed? I did have a look through the command line options for PHPUnit but there was nothing that obviously provided this functionality.
Test Start/End Date/Time would be useful: to prove that the tests were run before the update to the code was performed; identifying when the tests were performed to check that you have run the tests  before you perform your update.

Comment: Please check out the events system from phpunit: https://localheinz.com/articles/2023/02/14/extending-phpunit-with-its-new-event-system/